# Why does lassoing not work on my Plotly.js scatter plot when the date range is too high?

Tags: javascript, charts, plotly, scatter-plot, plotly.js

I posted this over at the Plotly community forum here: https://community.plotly.com/t/why-does-the-lasso-tool-pick-up-0-points-when-my-date-range-is-large/78025. I'm posting this again here to increase the chances of getting answers.

I have a Plotly.js scatter chart with lassoing enabled. I have dates along the x axis and various measures along the y. It seems that lassoing points works only below a certain date range, but beyond that it detects 0 points selected.

For example, here is a screen shot of the chart where the date range is Aug 14 2023 to Aug 23 2023:

[image]

I've lassoed a few points and the code below tells me I have 5 points lassoed:

```
chartDiv.on('plotly_selected', function(data) {
    $scope.selectedPoints = data.points;
});
```

Now I increase the date range to Aug 14 2022 to Aug 23 2023:

[image]

I lasso some points again but this time the code tells me I have 0 points lassoed.

I've narrowed down the threshhold to a date range of Aug 4 2023 to Aug 23 2023. Within that date range, points can still be lassoed. Beyond that date range, they can't.

Here are my data and layout (in that order). These are for a date range of Aug 3 2023 to Aug 23 2023 (just outside the range that works):

```
[
   {
      "type":"scatter",
      "x":[
         "2023-08-03T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-04T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-05T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-06T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-07T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-08T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-09T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-10T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-11T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-12T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-13T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-14T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-15T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-16T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-17T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-18T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-19T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-20T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-21T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-22T06:01:00.000Z"
      ],
      "y":[
         16.38888888888889,
         16.319444444444443,
         14.86111111111111,
         13.518518518518519,
         15.439814814814815,
         15.277777777777779,
         16.96759259259259,
         17.77777777777778,
         21.550925925925927,
         20.23148148148148,
         19.328703703703702,
         20.833333333333332,
         21.34259259259259,
         20.208333333333332,
         18.75,
         21.34259259259259,
         23.125,
         22.01388888888889,
         21.25,
         20
      ],
      "name":"°C",
      "marker":{
         "color":"red",
         "size":3,
         "opacity":1
      },
      "connectgaps":true,
      "measurementGroupId":18
   },
   {
      "type":"scatter",
      "x":[
         "2023-08-03T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-04T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-05T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-06T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-07T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-08T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-09T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-10T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-11T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-12T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-13T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-14T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-15T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-16T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-17T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-18T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-19T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-20T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-21T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-22T06:01:00.000Z"
      ],
      "y":[
         156.74999999999997,
         150.99,
         66.99000000000001,
         45.220000000000006,
         143.78000000000003,
         145.01999999999998,
         146.97,
         331.99,
         345.0000000000001,
         65,
         14,
         19,
         13.99,
         382.99,
         589.0400000000002,
         568,
         190.00000000000003,
         null,
         null,
         null
      ],
      "name":"m3",
      "marker":{
         "color":"blue",
         "size":3,
         "opacity":1
      },
      "yaxis":"y2",
      "connectgaps":true,
      "measurementGroupId":10
   },
   {
      "type":"scatter",
      "x":[
         "2023-08-03T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-04T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-05T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-06T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-07T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-08T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-09T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-10T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-11T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-12T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-13T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-14T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-15T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-16T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-17T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-18T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-19T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-20T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-21T06:01:00.000Z",
         "2023-08-22T06:01:00.000Z"
      ],
      "y":[
         19536.57,
         14615.99,
         11210.01,
         10693.779999999997,
         17339.200000000004,
         17433.34,
         17386.730000000007,
         16417.020000000004,
         14445.009999999998,
         10053.980000000001,
         10841.929999999998,
         10649.020000000004,
         -3833.99,
         12686.010000000004,
         15261.989999999998,
         14080.979999999998,
         9714.98,
         null,
         null,
         null
      ],
      "name":"kWh",
      "marker":{
         "color":"black",
         "size":3,
         "opacity":1
      },
      "yaxis":"y3",
      "connectgaps":true,
      "measurementGroupId":2
   }
]
```

```
{
   "title":{
      "text":"Time Series",
      "font":{
         "color":"#3dcd58",
         "family":"Nunito-Regular",
         "size":18
      },
      "xanchor":"left",
      "x":0
   },
   "font":{
      "color":"#333",
      "family":"Nunito-Regular"
   },
   "dragmode":"lasso",
   "autosize":false,
   "width":425,
   "height":400,
   "margin":{
      "l":20,
      "r":15,
      "b":25,
      "t":30
   },
   "plot_bgcolor":"#ffffff",
   "showlegend":true,
   "legend":{
      "x":0,
      "bgcolor":"rgba(255,255,255,0.3)"
   },
   "yaxis":{
      "showticklabels":false
   },
   "yaxis2":{
      "showticklabels":false,
      "overlaying":"y"
   },
   "yaxis3":{
      "showticklabels":false,
      "overlaying":"y"
   }
}
```

Is this a known bug? Am I doing something wrong? Thank you for any help!